# Dismissing a company doesn't help with the ads - still shows

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

With the new feature of dismissing a company in jobs I noticed some strange behavior.

When you dismiss a company the company still shows up in advertisements across the stackoverflow site.  Not really digging that type of functionality.  The job ad should rely on information such as this to simply not show me anything about this job.

Besides If I've dismissed a company why would I want to see an advertisement to work for this company?  Especially if it is on my list of "dismissed" companies.

For what it's worth I dismissed a company (I'd not like to say which but SO can reach out to me if they need this info) and upon dismissing this company the ads keep popping up from this same company.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this!

If that's happening for you, then it's a bug. Please email me the company you dismissed and a screenshot of the ad and I'll look into it.

Comment: @JonH 32 minutes later...

Comment: @JonH and what is the job that's being shown on the ad? or is the company page?

Comment: @JonH let us know if this comes up again. We couldn't reproduce it and haven't received any other reports. Thanks!